# Index healthy and statistics update after 1000 updates

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, indexing, statistics

I have a stored procedure which gets data from 5 tables. Tables are updated approximately 1000 records and 1000 updates in one hour. After inserting and updating, the stored procedure runs into a timeout.

When I rebuild one of the index of a table which is referenced in the stored procedure, it starts working normal again..  but it breaks down again after each new 1000 records updated.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think you are mistaken here when you say rebuilding the Index is solving the problem.

I think it is actually that rebuilding indexes invalids the the cached execution plan and on next execution after rebuilding the index will force sql server to recompile the execution plan.

Normally SQL Serve would use a cached execution plan for a stored procedure, but there are some factors that can cause sql server to recompile an execution plan for a stored procedure even if there a cached execution plan in proc cache memory. Rebuilding or any changes to an index that is being used in the execution of a stored procedure will result in recompilation of execution plan.

Since you are inserting 1000 rows every hour and you would also want to keep your statistics updated. I would say run an nightly job to update statistics.

But for your Store Procedure use `WITH RECOMPILE` option in your procedure's definition or use this option when executing this Stored Procedure and I think it will solve the issue.

to add this option in sp's definition

```
ALTER PROCEDURE myProc
WITH RECOMPILE
AS.......
```

Or to add this option when executing your stored procedure you can do as follows

```
EXECUTE myProc WITH RECOMPILE
```

Or you can also use a system stored procedure `sp_recompile` to force sql server to compile an execution plan even if there is one in cache memory.

```
EXECUTE sp_recompile N'dbo.MyProc';
GO

EXECUTE dbo.MyPrco;
GO
```